# "Cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities ...", but it should

Tags: linq-to-entities, group-by, linq-to-objects, datepart

This sould be able to be translated into a Linq to entities store expression, but it throws that it cant.

```
for (int day = 1; day <= 7; day = day + 1)
   pairs.Add("[" + day + ", " + db.Messages.Count(m => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", m.Date) == day) + "]");
```

**What is the problem?**

Also, I'm using 7 queries to the database. **Should I just do one, using GroupBy?**